# Fill Blank Cell with specific values More than 100,000 Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am using an common way that is Selected the range and opens Find and Replace windows then mention specific value in that then replace it with empty cells, this process takes long time.

Then i tried with VBA but it is time taking process as well. I hope there must be any fast way to achieving this.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub fillblankcells()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("Done")

For Each rng In ws.Range("B2:AB120000")
If IsEmpty(rng) Then
rng.Value = 0
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `ws.Range("B2:AB120000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = 0`

Comment: @ScottCraner - I think you might get inconsistent results with `SpecialCells` depending on the last filled cell on the sheet.

Comment: yup, you nailed it,  special cells only uses the used range on the sheet.  so making sure that AB120000 as you did is filled is correct.  Also one may want to make sure there is at least 1 blank cell before calling to ensure no errors. @BigBen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following. You need to ensure `AB120000` is filled before calling `SpecialCells`.

```
If IsEmpty(ws.Range("AB120000")) Then
    ws.Range("AB120000").Value = 0
End If

On Error Resume Next ' ignore error if no blank cells
ws.Range("B2:AB120000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = 0
On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea:

I created an Excel sheet, where the cells B2, B120000, AB2 and AB120000 and some random others (inside that area) were filled.
In the "Name box", I entered the range `B2:AB120000`.
I pressed <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> (Goto), asked for `Special`, and chose `Blanks`, that took about a minute.
In the address bar, I typed `0` and pressed <kbd>Ctrl+ENTER</kbd>.

In less than 2 minutes, all blanks were replaced by zero.

The first comment and answer your received are an automation of this action.

**Edit**
In case you are interested in the `Not Applicable` value, you can enter `=NA()` instead of `0` in the address bar.

Where to put the range? You can see this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am confused that where to enter the range. Can you please tell and i want to replace the empty cell with `Not Applicable` value